# Modeling arrays in Java when using api calls with retrofit

Tags: java, arrays, retrofit

I am using retrofit to make api calls and I am unsure what the best practice for modling the returned data is.

Currently the one API call returns a String and an array.  The array holds another array, and each of those arrays hold array of key value pairs.

so we have

```
String1 = "success"
Array1{array2{"Name":"Adam", "Location":"Cape Town"}, {"Name":"Jon", "Location":"Pretoria"}};
```

Currently to house these I have a class for the innermost array with a setter and getter for name and location.  Then I have another class that just has a setter and getter for a List of the first array, then I have a third class that has a setter and getter for the outermost array as well as a setter and getter for a String.

This feels really bad as for each of my many API calls I have 3 Model classes.

Comment: @asteriskNinja Just a note. If you're going to recommend people go to Codereview, please point out that they **will** need to re-write their question to avoid it being closed. In this case, the OP would need to embed all the code that they want reviewed directly in the question.

Comment: @asteriskNinja Questions asking "What is best practice?" and questions containing pseudocode are both off-topic on Code Review.